# NULL as an eighth 'primitive' data type

Tags: java, java-8, javac, primitive-types

A mindless query arising from Java's less known data type 'null'.

Would somebody be able to clarify whether or not 'null' is a literal reserved by the Java language and thus the disparity between it satisfying as primitive data type and a digital value?

```
NULL default_object_value; // a Syntax error
NULL acct_balance_at_westbank = null; // Another Syntax error

String aStrokeOfLuck = null; // a feasible variable declaration & assignment
```

Comment: What is "the disparity between it satisfying as primitive data type and a digital value"?

Comment: null is not data type, it is special literal that can be used as a **value** for any **reference type**

Comment: btw, `String` is not primitive data type, it is reference as any object

Comment: The _null_ value cannot be used with _primitive data-types_, only _Objects_.

Comment: There is no syntax error in your code example. You’ll get an error about an unresolved identifier unless you create a class named `NULL`. If you create a class named `NULL`, the code will pass. In other words, it’s syntactically valid but it depends on the environment whether it can be compiled. That’s not different to the example’s last line which depends on the presence on the class `String`. Syntactically, there is no difference between your made-up identifier `NULL` and the commonly known identifier `String`.

Comment: And, by the way, your counting is off. Letting aside that null is not a primitive type, there are already eight primitive types, `boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int`, `long`, `float`, and `double`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to JLS 4.1, there actually is a type for `null`.

> *"There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null (§3.10.8, §15.8.1), which has no name."* - [JLS 4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)

So.

1. `null` is a literal reserved by the Java language.
2. `null` denotes a value not a type.
3. The type of `null` cannot be named.  Hence your failed attempts to do that.

   (I don't even think there is a reflective `java.lang.Class` representation for the null type ...)
4. The JLS says that the type of `null` is *neither* a primitive type *or* a reference type.
5. Various contexts allow `null` to be converted to the null value of any reference type; e.g.

> *"Finally, a value of the null type (the null reference is the only such value) may be assigned to any reference type, resulting in a null reference of that type."* - [JLS 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

<sup>I imagine that there is some technical reason that they have chosen to specify the null type this way.  Maybe this makes other parts of the spec simpler.  I don't know.  And unless you are a black-belt type theoretician, the *why* question is most likely irrelevant.</sup>

---

> ... the disparity between it satisfying as primitive data type and a digital value?

I cannot make sense of that part of your question.

---

As mentioned in the comments, `NULL` is just an ordinary identifier.  The Java class libraries don't declare a class with that name, and as such you will most likely get an unresolved symbol error.  You could declare one for yourself, but that `NULL` class will not (and cannot) denote the null type as far as the Java compiler or runtime is concerned.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. There is no `java.lang.Class` representation for the null type and since you can’t invoke `getClass()` on a `null` reference, you won’t miss it.